# Need to recover project in NetBeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I accidentally created a new project that had the same name so it overwrote the project I needed in netbeans. I need to recover this file.

when going to history and trying to revert it nothing shows up

I tried going to the filehistory file and found what I think was the file but when I open it it displays a mumbled mess of text that looks like this:
PK  ç[SS
1634657442226íkSÛºò;¿B“O¡ÎiÂãœv ÐœI7    í™Óét„­ÅÊ±e(=—ÿ~WòKŠeãBÓ;73ÇÚ]íCÒ®V^7¶6Ð1d_coB¿vD]›xA×;Äß†6Æàg/¾ý^Þë¡Ÿ}#6ß3âs—–'ÓÅœ ±KIJnÄ
ÐÐ(n
&ö¤<@$žý&ŽË™/zhlÌ°}ƒ¡ƒé½å…Ó

is there a way I can fix this or is my file gone forever.

Comment: That file is a zip file. Try renaming it to *.zip and looking inside.

Comment: After I turn it into zip when I try and open it windows blocks it saying it could potentially be harmful.